# netbeans Maven PlugIn does not update remote repo index

Tags: maven, netbeans

I am starting with a project where I want to use latest versions of hibernate and the hibernate spatial extension. Therefore I decided to start with a maven project to manage all the dependencies. I have to say, that I am pretty unexperienced both in using maven an the maven netbeans plugin, but I think it is the best option for my requirements. I am using Netbeans 7.2.1.

There is a short and simple description how to add the remote repos for hibernate spatial to maven (http://www.hibernatespatial.org/mavenquick.html).

I added these repo's in netbeans - services - maven repositories. Then I clicked on "Update Index" but nothing happens.

I also tried to open the repo Url in my Browser and I got all the files that it should deliver.

Why is Netbeans not updating the index? Is there a possibility to index the remote repo on maven commandline so that I am able to bypass netbeans and possibly get more info about what is happening?

Comment: Additional questions come up: 1. where does netbeans store its maven repo information? 2. how does netbeans interact with maven to update repo and dependency information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you adding the repo you need into your *{home}/.m2/settings.xml* file (or alternatively your pom file in the project). That's where your **Maven** installation takes the configurations from at first. So that way you avoid using **NetBeans** to do that and you'll be sure that Maven will be using that repo no matter the way you call it (NetBeans embedded, command line...).

Add this repositories into your file:

```
<repository>
    <id>OSGEO GeoTools repo</id>
    <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>Hibernate Spatial repo</id>
    <url>http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository</url>
</repository>
```

You'll probably find this [guide from Maven official site](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories) useful.

Comment: Ok, as I didn't had an initial settings.xml in my profile, i copied the one from /etc/maven/settings.xml as mentioned in the guide. I opened the profiles tag and added my remote repos, I think I did everything right, and maven should recognize it now, but I want to use the full Netbeans integration, because I am developing in netbeans at least. My changes didn't affect netbeans at all, it still shows only the repos I added over the UI. When I ask it to update indizes, nothing happens. When I want to add the hibernate spatial dependency to my project, it doesn't find it.

Comment: I don't know the way Netbeans plugin works, but I use the plugin for Eclipse and that way works. Why don't you just forget about the ui and try to do a `mvn compile` or `mvn install` of the project? That should download that repo attached dependencies for your projects. If not, go to the project root through command line and execute `mvn install`.

Comment: Yeah, i could but the point is i WANT to use an IDE so i do not have to matter about commands of the different frameworks i use in my development process. Also I am not able to add a bibrary to my project in netbeans if the maven plugin doesnt recognize it. So i have three options: a) typing in vi, compiling on commandline b) dont use maven in netbeans c) use eclipse and maven

Comment: But thank you so far, i will go through the maven guide. Perhaps its the best solution to use eclipse; )

Comment: Let me give you an advice, IDE plugins usually turn to create problems with Maven, just try to understand Maven itself and don't focus very much into the plugins, they can let you crazy.

Comment: I got it, the problem was, I did not READ the hibernate spatial quickstart. It is not necessary to add the remote repo's to mavens settings xml. In this case I only need to add the repo's to the projects pom.xml (that was the part I didn't read or fully understand actually). Doing it like this, everything works like a charm, althought I am using netbeans. Thanks so far, +1 and acceptance for giving the advice to "understand" maven and what it is doing... ;)

Comment: You are welcome man, keep in mind that plugins are only a help, everything you can do with them is also possible using maven commands. And this settings.xml file is a way to configure global  settings, so if you add repos on it, you should be able  use them from any of your poms. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

> I added these repo's in netbeans - services - maven repositories. Then I clicked on "Update Index" but nothing happens.

1. The Services/Maven repositories node only deals with indexes that help with some IDE searching capabilities. It's not affecting build in any way. If you want to change your build, either add it to pom.xml or to settings.xml in the usual maven manner. Please note that such active repositories should effectively show up in your Services node in the end.
2. Update Index action attempts to download the index from the remote location. There are multiple points of failure here. The repository might not provide an index, or your maven proxy settings don't allow you to connect (we use explicitly maven settings, not IDE proxy settings), your mirrors defined in settings.xml mirror this repository but don't provide the content for it.
3. Even if the index is downloaded and processed (you can browse the content in Services node), the individual artifacts might be missing from the index because the server side job updates only occasionally.
4. In any case you are not limited in any way when not having the index around. You can still add the dependency to the project if you know the coordinates. Either through the UI or by editing the pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Using version 11 of Netbeans I have been able to force the download of last archetype-catalog.xml from remote repo by deleting the cache ([].netbeans.cache\11\mavenarchetypes).